# How to convert NSString to string without changing any special characters?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms. I am trying to convert NSString to string.

When it has got converted, i found some of the special characters are changed in the converted string.

e.g., Consider my NSString value as GJDK'"007, while on converting it to string, it has got changed like GJDK '\"007.

Guide me in converting the NSString value to string without changing any of the special characters.

Comment: Looks like something is escaping the string.  However, you posted no code, so we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: The escaped .Net `String` is equal the original `NSString`, What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am binding this value in XAML. Because of this kind of conversion, the value is displayed as GJDK. But that should display GJDK '"007. @SushiHangover

Comment: @GJDK How about some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Ok lemme ask you in this way. Consider am going to assign the string value to the string from the constant file. The value that is to be assigned is received from the service as NSSting. On that scenario, am converting that NSString value to string(C#) to assign it to the constant file's string. e.g., var row = new Dictionary<object, object>();
       row.Add(EmployeeConstants.ID, (string)obj.EmpId);      "obj" is the value from service and am converting that as string to assign it to the Employee Constants ID value.